# El layout de trabajo es demasiado pequeño para trabajar Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola soy nuevo en stackoverflow,
Mi problema es que cuando creo un proyecto nuevo con una Activity vacia o cualquier otra, en el blueprint no se me muestra como deberia, sino un layout sobre el que trabajo de un pixel, es decir si yo arrastro cuadros de texto, botones, etc no se ven por que estan como en un layout muy pequeño. Los parametros de altura y anchura del layout creo que son los correctos. Bueno os dejo unas fotos de como deberia ser y como me sale a mi y el codigo XML de la vista.

En el blueprint incorrecto que es el que me sale a mi, el pixel blanco dentro del circulo rojo es donde se guardan los botones y demas que voy añadiendo al proyecto, se quedan ahi todos juntos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Blueprint correcto]

[image: Blueprint incorrecto]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No has dejado imágenes de cómo se ve, edita tu pregunta y añade la información necesaria.

Comment: las fotos que donde están, edita la pregunta

Comment: Perdona ya las he puesto

Comment: En la ultima imagen que colocaste le estas asignando un tamaño definido a **android:layout_width** y **android:layout_height** esa podría ser la razón de por que se ve pequeño.

Comment: Probare a cambiarlo pero esos valores están asi de probar diferentes opciones. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: @DavidDeLaVarga el layout que debes agregar el activity_main.xml

Comment: @Jorgesys♦ no entiendo muy bien lo que me quieres decir, perdona. Si te refieres al código del activity_main.xml esta más arriba.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, alguien tiene solución?

Comment: @AlexRodriguez Yo opte por instalar Android studio en Linux y me funciona bien. Creo que tiene que ver con la version del procesador, el mio es  un intel de primera generacion y creo que hay algun problema con alguna version.